# Adding elements to ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#

```
ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList(5);
        arrayList1.Add(new List<int>());
        arrayList1[0].Add(3);
```

Why doesn't this work? How can I fix this one?

Comment: `(arrayList1[0] as List<int>).Add(3);`

Comment: Don't use `ListArray`, rather `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: ArrayList is an older technology, it´s origin was when a `List<>` did not exist. So rather go with a `List<>` and try to avoid using an `ArrayList<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply this can add list of **int**

```
  List<List<int>> arrayList1 = new List<List<int>>();
  arrayList1.Add(new List<int>());
```